# How to replace strings of a text file based on two list using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a text file like this:

test.list

```
##a
##b
##C
#CHROM  0_62000_1       0_62000_5       0_62070_19        0_62000
```

I have OLD_SM.list

```
0_62000_1
0_62000
0_62070_19
```

and NEW_SM.list

```
APPLE
BANANA
KIWI
```

I want to replace the word in test.list that match in OLD_SM.list with NEW_SM.list.

I would prefer sed command, so I tried something like this which doesn't work.

```
paste OLD_SM.list NEW_SM.list | while read OLD_SM NEW_SM; do sed -i "/^#CHROM/s/[[:space:]]${OLD_SM}$/\t${NEW_SM}/g" test.list; done
```

Result I want

```
##a
##b
##C
#CHROM  APPLE       0_62000_5       KIWI        BANANA
```

Comment: Does it __have to__ be sed?

Comment: @KamilCuk It is part of a pipeline I am working on, so I would prefer sed or a oneliner.

Comment: `I would prefer` so it's a preference. `or a oneliner.` just replace newlines with `;` and it becomes one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed you can match beginning and ending of a word with `\<` `\>`. You may first generate a sed script from your input then pass it to sed. There have to be no special characters in input.

```
script=$(
      paste OLD_SM.list NEW_SM.list |
      sed 's/\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/s~\\<\1\\>~\2~g/'
)
sed -i "/^#CHROM/{ $script }" file.
```

The `s/[[:space:]]${OLD_SM}$` - the `$` matches end of line, so it's never going to work. You may do `s/\(^\|[[:space:]]\)$OLD_SM\([[:space:]]\|$\)/\1$NEW_SM\2/` - match beginning of a line or space, then the word, then space or ending of line, and then substitute for backreference. Topics to research: regex and backreferences in sed.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `paste + awk` solution:

```sh
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR == FNR { map[$1]=$2; next} $1 == "#CHROM" {for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) $i in map && $i=map[$i]} 1' <(paste OLD_SM.list NEW_SM.list) test.list

##a
##b
##C
#CHROM  APPLE   0_62000_5   KIWI    BANANA
```

Expanded form:

```sh
awk -v OFS='\t' '
NR == FNR {
   map[$1] = $2
   next
}
$1 == "#CHROM" {
   for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i)
      $i in map && $i = map[$i]
}
1' <(paste OLD_SM.list NEW_SM.list) test.list
```

Comment: Nice answer and it'll work for any characters in any of the 3 files, unlike the currently posted sed solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different take: build up the sed program as a bash array:

```sh
sed_opts=()

while read -r old <&3; read -r new <&4; do
    sed_opts+=( -e "s/\\<$old\\>/$new/g" )
done 3< OLD_SM.list 4< NEW_SM.list

sed "${sed_opts[@]}" test.list
```